# Java - XML to JSON Conversion ( org.json.JSONException: Mismatched meta and head at character 573 )

Tags: java, json, xml

I am trying to convert the response of my API which is XML to JSON String. But it is throwing the following error:

**org.json.JSONException: Mismatched meta and head at character 573**

**Java Code**

```
final String API_URI = "https://221.120.211.69:443/abl-api/uat/ApiConnectFTwsdlDefinitionHttpService";

        final ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();

        final Client client = Client.create(config);

        final WebResource resource = client.resource(API_URI);

        MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
        queryParams.add("SystemName", "CDC");
        queryParams.add("RequestID", "222");
        queryParams.add("TenantID", "abc11323===+");
        queryParams.add("CreditAccount", "0010000108290010");
        queryParams.add("DebitAmount", "100");
        queryParams.add("MappingID", "Remarks");
        queryParams.add("Narration", "remarks");
        WebResource webResource = client.resource(API_URI);

        JSONObject requestObj = new JSONObject();           

        requestObj.put("SystemName", "CDC");
        requestObj.put("RequestID", "222");
        requestObj.put("TenantID", "abc11323===+");
        requestObj.put("CreditAccount", "0010000108290010");
        requestObj.put("DebitAmount", "100");
        requestObj.put("MappingID", "Remarks");
        requestObj.put("Narration", "remarks");

        ClientResponse responseMsg = webResource
        .queryParams(queryParams)
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
        .header("SOAPAction", "http://ApiConnectFTwsdlDefinition/FundsTransfer")
        .header("X-IBM-Client-Id", "0146b9a4-7e99-4c83-8e9e-6049cfec55da")
        .header("Authorization", "Bearer "+ "AAIkMDE0NmI5YTQtN2U5OS00YzgzLThlOWUtNjA0OWNmZWM1NWRh5BUqmbzniU-ky5TE1-NI9I4IwXqdU8_EEzAEe6QVdclRLwQlVxuO03e3xAVKKOc3xstoep8xbkjK5t3ffbCRJR6xlcGdoS3nvGmEoMYgbesChrbhrAnu6uVS8g-JRSGWaqwqTf-DRQRBRi6ysKEOOg")
        .post(ClientResponse.class, requestObj);


        JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(responseMsg.getEntity(String.class));
        String jsonPrettyPrintString = xmlJSONObj.toString(4);
        //System.out.println(xmlJSONObj.toString());
        System.out.println(jsonPrettyPrintString);
        //System.out.println(responseMsg.getEntity(String.class));
```

I have tried to change the XML to String and JSON Entities and changed the JSON Pretty constant number but nothing changed.

Can anybody help?

Comment: How are you converting from xml to json?

Comment: Please check the last three line of my provided code

Comment: What is the value of `responseMsg.getEntity(String.class)`? is it a valid xml?

Comment: You may try alternative converter. Underscore-java library has static method U.xmlToJson(xml).

Comment: I would suspect that the input is HTML rather than XML, but without seeing it, that's a wild guess.

Comment: You may try to convert html to the xml with help of htmlunit.

Comment: Well I converted my response from String to Hashmap and used the key instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well I converted my response from String to Hashmap and used the key instead.